# How can my MIDI master keyboard send all MIDI messages _except_ "program change" to receiving synth modules?

Tags: midi, synthesizer, studio

I still use my trusty Yamaha AN1x synthesizer as my master keyboard for my DAW and to control other desktop synths and tone generators. For example, my AN1x currently sends MIDI to both a Waldorf Blofeld desktop synth and a Yamaha Mu-80 tone generator.

There's one thing I'm embarrassed to be having trouble with, though: when I move through the programs/patches on my AN1x (the master keyboard), it sends program change messages to the Blofeld and Mu80, too, which is really annoying if I'm trying to create specific, layered, multitimbral sounds.

**How can I ensure that changing the program on my AN1x doesn't cause the recipient devices to change *their* programs?** I'd still like to send all other performance messages, if possible.

Do I somehow tell the AN1x not to send such a thing? Or do I tell the Blofeld and Mu80 to ignore it? A cursory re-re-re-read of my instruction manuals proved fruitless.

Whew. This is the kind of thing I feel like I would've easily known how to do as a synthpop-worshiping teenager in the late 90s, but I've forgotten how after years of a dismantled setup and mostly software use.

Comment: Isn‘t there for each data and feature a channel number that you can turn on/off by mouse click?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli That isn't what OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manual, the AN1x has no mechanism to prevent sending only program change messages.

According to the manual, the Blofeld allows ignoring program change messages with the setting "Prg Change" on the fifth Multimode Receive page.

According to the manual, the MU80 allows ignoring program change messages with the multipart parameter "Rcv PROGRAM CHANGE"; this must be set with a SysEx message at address `08 nn 32`.

Comment: I will endeavor to sharpen my manual-reading skills in the future. Thank you!